# Compute all prefix sums in purely functional programming style in O(n) time in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, purely-functional, prefix-sum

Is it possible to compute all prefix sums for an array of numbers in [purely functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming) style in O(n) time in Kotlin?

What I mean by purely functional programming is allowing using functional programming extension functions for collections only, such as `map`, `reduce`, `fold`, `sum`, etc. in [_Collections,kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt), while traditional imperative programming methods involving changing state and mutable data such as ordinary loops, mutable variables aka `var`s, and mutable arrays are not allowed. (I think this conforms to the definition on Wikipedia)

To be more specific, here are one example of what I want to achieve written in imperative programming that runs in O(n) time, and another in functional programming that runs in O(n^2) time.

```
fun prefixSumsImperative(numbers: IntArray): IntArray {
    val prefixSums = IntArray(numbers.size)
    var prefixSum = 0
    for ((i, number) in numbers.withIndex()) {
        prefixSum += number
        prefixSums[i] = prefixSum
    }
    return prefixSums
}

fun prefixSumsFunctionalONSquared(numbers: IntArray): IntArray =
    (0 until numbers.size).map { numbers.take(it).sum() }.toIntArray()
```

Comment: The helper function you'd be looking for is often called [a `scan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl), but does't appear to be available in Kotlin. You can emulate it though by building a linked list in a `fold` operation and reversing it afterwards (or doing `foldRight`).

Comment: Update: [scan](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/scan.html) is available in Kotlin now, though it's temporarily experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, solving this problem requires persistent stack, which is not presented in standard Kotlin library. But stack can be imitated with pairs:

```
fun prefixSumsFunctionalPuzzler(numbers: IntArray): IntArray =
    generateSequence(numbers.fold(Any() to 0) { stack, value ->
        stack to stack.second + value
    }) { it.first as Pair<Any, Int> }
        .map { it.second }
        .take(numbers.size)
        .toList().asReversed().toIntArray()
```

Comment: You could use `generateSequence` instead of `Stream.iterate`.

Answer (score 3):

As of Kotlin 1.4 you can use `scan` and `runningFold` functions for this purpose:

```
fun prefixSumsFunctional(numbers: IntArray): IntArray =
    numbers.runningFold(0) { sum, num ->
        sum + num
    }.toIntArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution meets all your requirements, for a functional style:

```
fun prefixSumsFunctional(numbers: IntArray): IntArray =
    numbers.fold(listOf<Int>()) { result, el ->
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result + el
        } else {
            result + (result.last() + el)
        }
    }.toIntArray()
```

Comment: It runs in _O(n^2)_ because of the list connection running in _O(n)_.

Comment: @Bananon Yes you are right, but this is only a problem of this list implementation. I could use Vavr or some other persistent list.

Comment: Could it be argued `fold` violates the definition of purely functional the OP gave? It basically provides a mutable variable to use alongside your function.

Comment: @Tenfour04 `fold` doesn't provide a mutable variable, it only guarantees that it will give you the value which was returned at the previous step. You can even implement `fold` without using `var` keyword: `tailrec fun <R> IntArray.fold(initial: R, start: Int = 0, operation: (acc: R, Int) -> R): R = if (start < size) fold(operation(initial, this[start]), start + 1, operation) else initial`.